# What does `_inner` mean in a Struct?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I was looking at the [EnumerableSet.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol) contract from [OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/) and I saw this:

```
struct Bytes32Set {
    Set _inner;
}
```

What does `_inner` mean?

Is it a copy of the following?

```
struct Set {
    // Storage of set values
    bytes32[] _values;
    // Position of the value in the `values` array, plus 1 because index 0
    // means a value is not in the set.
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) _indexes;
}
```

So `Bytes32Set` is basically `Set` but with a different name? Where can I read about `_inner` in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this smart contract in `Bytes32Set` struct is using `Set` struct. In others words there _inner is Set struct's variable inside Bytes32 struct. This is an example of use a struct in other struct.
It is similar to do this:

```
struct Bytes32Set {
  _inner {
    // These are the variables inside 'Set' struct
    bytes32[] _values;
    mapping(bytes32 => uint256) _indexes;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So `Bytes32Set` is basically `Set` but with a different name?

Comment: Bytes32Set is a new struct that inside have Set struct